# 'set' command not working on tcsh shell when called explicitly

Tags: linux, tcsh

The `set` command works fine when I type it like this:

```
echo $0
/usr/bin/tcsh
echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/tcsh
set START_TIME=`date +%s`
echo $START_TIME
1499360060
```

However, it doesn't work when I call it explicitly in `tcsh` like this:

```
/usr/bin/tcsh -i -f -c 'set START_TIME=`date +%s`'
echo $START_TIME
START_TIME: Undefined variable.
```

I tried to do this with `setenv` at first, but then realized that child process cannot run `setenv` command. So, I figured `set` is the way to go. Please advise if there's another better way to go about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are setting the variable in a subshell which then terminates, taking your variable with it.  To demonstrate:

```
$ /bin/tcsh -ifc 'set VARIABLE=foo; echo $VARIABLE'; echo ${VARIABLE-blank}
foo
blank
```

(My main shell is `bash`; the second `echo` uses a `bash`ism to give a default value for an undefined or null variable expansion)